# ctrlp fuzzy search string in all file in directory

Tags: vim, ctrlp

Using ctrlp, I would like to search for a string in all files in the current directory ( or a specified directory).

Using the "lines" mode is only searching for files opened. I would like to search for all files, including the files not opened.

Thanks in advance.